# Verificar se a checkbox está marcada ou desmarcada ao carregar a página e alterar a classe para ativado

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Através do local storage eu consigo sempre manter a checkbox ativa ou desativada mesmo se a pagina for recarregada, o problema é que eu não consegui validar se ao carregar a pagina a checkbox está marcada ou desmacrada para mudar a cor da label.

```js
// Verificar se a checkbox está marcada e adicionar a classe ativado
if ($("#id-box-1").prop("checked")){
$('#id-box-1-cor').toggleClass('ativado');
     }

// Esta parte do código insere 1 ou 0 quando ha mudaça na checkbox
$('.chamados-header-item-dispo-box-bg').on("change", function() {
 if ($(this).find(".i-check").is(':checked')){
  $(this).find(".i-value")[0].value = "1";      
   } else {
  $(this).find(".i-value")[0].value = "0";
  }
 Aqui é feito o submit /*$(this).find(".i-value")[0].form.submit();*/
});
```

```css
.i-check{}
.chamados-header-item-dispo-box-bg{float:left;}
.chamados-header-item-dispo-box {height:55px;width:55px;margin-left:10px;padding: 20px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; box-shadow:-1px -1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);border-radius:5%;background-color:var(--cor-branco)}
.ativado{background: #28a745;}
.i-value{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <!-- Box 1 -->
    <div class="chamados-header-item-dispo-box-bg">
      <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" id="id-box-1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="id-box-1">
      <div class="chamados-header-item-dispo-box" id='id-box-1-cor'></div>
     </label>
     <input class="i-value" type="text" name="box1">
    </div>
    <!-- Box 2 -->
    <div class="chamados-header-item-dispo-box-bg">
      <input class="i-check" type="checkbox" id="id-box-2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="id-box-2">
       <div class="chamados-header-item-dispo-box"></div>
      </label>
      <input class="i-value" type="text" name="box2">
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Eu já tentei de tudo, .is(':checked'), prop, attr, mas de forma alguma consegui validar com precisão. Se possível como eu tenho várias dessas box, então eu preciso que ao carregar saber qual das checkbox está marcada através do id="id-box-1", id="id-box-2"... e alterar a  <div class="chamados-header-item-dispo-box" id='id-box-1-cor'></div> usando apenas a classe = "chamados-header-item-dispo-box";

Comment: Eu removei o display: none; da i-check, para que vocês consigam visualizar; Quando a mudanças na checkbox o valor é trocado corretamente, o problema está apenas na cor da box. Como eu mando para outra página para inserir o valor 1 ou 0 no banco, pensei em utilizar o storage para manter a cor de acordo, mas não há problema em fazer um select no banco para talvez buscar este status após a pagina for carrega.